UEFI Secure Boot from SSDs on RAID controller does not boot if secure boot activated
I have a severe problem with a server equipped with a RAID controller on the PCI bus. This is neither an OS-specifc (Linux/Windows) nor hardware-specifc (RAID vendor) problem:
Machine has two NVMe SSDs in a RAID-1 on the RAID controller. I install my OS from an USB stick (here: Linux) while the UEFI Secure Boot mode is OFF. The UEFI presents all kinds of boot options: harddisk, CD/DVD-ROM, USB, my RAID1-SSDs on the RAID controller, network devices for PXE boot, etc. Please do note that the UEFI states 'if Secure Boot off, then Legacy BIOS is also enabled'.
Installation from USB to NVMe SSDs on RAID works. Machine is rebooted to check the OS installation again with Secure Boot mode OFF. Everyhting's fine. The SSD has a GPT with an ESP (type 0xEF00, partition 1) and the SHIM bootloader (because I am using Linux in this example) plus a big fat LVM2 GPT partition #2 with the OS on it.
Entering the UEFI setup, I activate Secure Boot now. This UEFI tells me that it requires a reboot for this change to take effect. OK. Done. After it has rebooted, it stops displaying 'no bootable devices available'.
If I open up the list with boot options, I see only two options left:

the UEFI boot entry that was created by the Linux installer for my OS - this is the Boot0001 EFI variable (manually checked the content, everything OK, also the UEFI device path specification to the SHIM bootloader);
boot from USB.

If I select my UEFI boot entry, only a blank screen is shown for a few seconds and the UEFI returns to the boot menu. No harddisk, no network devices for PXE, nothing shown as additional boot options (they just vanished). If I insert the Linux OS installer in the USB and select that entry (2nd boot option), then the installer also boots in UEFI secure boot mode, i.e. the UEFI secure boot generally works.
Question: Is it possible that the UEFI BIOS lacks UEFI driver support for my (Broadcom) quadport network card as well as for the RAID controller with the two NVMe SSDs?
If Secure Boot is ON (no custom keys, all default stuff from the OEM plus Microsoft keys), then no legacy BIOS (NIC, RAID) is active (in contradiction to the secure boot off case). OK. But from where does the UEFI gets additional UEFI drivers for peripherals like the Braodcom network (PXE boot) or the RAID controller???
I did read the whole UEFI specification, version 2.10. Is this a gap in the spec.? Do I miss something? Can the UEFI get additional driver support from the PCI hardware's firmware (ACPI memory region?), maybe? Would it be sufficient to update all controller firmwares to succeed here?
I am totally lost.

I read the whole UEFI specification, version 2.10 what happened when you ran the OS installation with SecureBoot enabled?

System could NOT boot because the UEFI BIOS disabled ALL legacy BIOS if Secure Boot enabled. It could not find the harddisk (in my case, two SSDs in a RAID-1 on the PCI RAID controller). Do you know if this is correct: UEFI BIOS in Secure Boot Mode can only boot from devices directly connected via mainboard components? This would also mean: If you want to perform PXE boot, then this would also only possible for onboard NICs not for NICs on the PCI bus. Correct?

This is obviously dependent on the hardware platform. Suffice it to say that UEFI SecureBoot has been around 15? years and is quite mature and is in nearly all hardware for years. That said, Microsoft created Windows 11 precisely to finish off the glaringly slow uptake. In a Windows environment, "switching" from legacy to UEFI SecureBoot it is not uncommon to be a pave and reinstall operation...

Thank you Greg. Yes, UEFI SB is around for maybe even more than 15 years. I am wondering why there is still so much open in the specification (2.238 pages in v2.10)? I could give you several examples proving that. What is definitely missing, is the following: UEFI folks, add an option to load additional EFI binaries (of course: PKCS#7 signed, hashes in 'db') containing device driver code for SCSI controllers, RAID controllers, NICs, etc., which are not present on the mainboard but on the PCI bus, BEFORE the UEFI code checks the BootNNNN EFI variables trying to find 'bootable' stuff.

I finally found the answer on www.reddit.com
The opROMs of the various hardware components not part of the mainboard come with legacy BIOS AND with UEFI drivers.
If you activate Secure Boot, then no legacy BIOS is used anymore because these are never signed. Only if your non-mainboard hardware (on the PCI bus) comes with one or more opROM(s) that also has an UEFI driver in it, then your UEFI firmware uses it IF AND ONLY IF it is able to verify the digital signature of the UEFI driver.
The vast majority of all UEFI drivers get signed by the Microsoft PCA (I think this is Program Compatibility Assistant?) code signing facility, which means that you have to install the full X.509 certificate chain in the EFI variable 'db'.
An alternative is described here, which is technically very elaborated, and you DO need a TPM 2.0 in your box. This is used in terms of the so called BIOS measurements, i.e. the TPM register PCR No. 2 lists all SHA-256 hashes of all UEFI drivers found during the boot process.
You have to extract all these SHA-256 message digests storing them in the EFI variable 'db'. This also works (successfully tested).
The problem with the Microsoft certificates is not only that you would have to trust Microsoft 'as a whole'. These certificates expire in the next few years and have to be replaced by new ones. This would immediately break your Secure Boot setup. Of course, you would also need updated UEFI drivers with updated digital signatures in this scenario.
